# Array from api response without true and false attributes received to dynamically create checkboxes in React

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I created dynamic checkboxes from api results in React-Redux web application but the problem is that the checkboxes results don't updated on onClick, setting the new state. Should be able to update the state using setState function.

I tried using the solution from this link below but it didn't work for me because the payload I am receiving from the api, does not contain checked attributes or true/false attributes.

[Make an API call to dynamically create checkboxes in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543118/make-an-api-call-to-dynamically-create-checkboxes-in-react)

The payload I received is as follows:

```
flavors: Array(3)
0: {id: "1001", name: "Spicy"}
1: {id: "1002", name: "Hot"}
2: {id: "1003", name: "Mediterranean"}
```

Which should populate:

```
getInitialState = () => {

  const initialState = {
      customer: {
                  id: '',
                  firstName: '',
                  lastName: '',
                  email: ''        
                },
     flavours: []    //Array to be populated, what is desired: {Spicy: false, 
                     // Hot: false, Mediterranean: false} 
                     // is populated currently as : Spicy, Hot, 
                     //   Mediterranean
      },
  return initialState;
 }
```

get payload from api  and checkbox handler method:

```
 getAllFlavours() {
   const { dispatch } = this.props;
   dispatch(userActions.getFlavours()).then((response) => {
   var flavourList = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < response.flavours.length; i++) {
      flavourList.push(response.flavours[i].name);
    }
    this.setState({
      flavours: flavourList,
     });
   });
 }

 handleCheckboxChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const isChecked = target.checked;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({ flavours: { ...this.state.flavours, [name]: 
    isChecked } });
  }
```

create checkboxes method:

```
render() {

let flavourCheckboxes = this.state.flavours.map((item, i) => {
  return (<FormGroup key={i}>
     <Col>
      <Label key={i}>{item}</Label>
      </Col>
      <Col>
      <Input key={i} name={item} type="checkbox" checked={item} onClick= 
       {this.handleCheckboxChange} />
      </Col>
    </FormGroup>)
 });

 return (
 // other html tags
   <CardBody>
      <Row>
         {flavourCheckboxes}  // checkboxes created
      </Row>
   </CardBody>
   // other html tags
```

I expect the checkbox to be able to check and uncheck also updating the state when that is triggered by the onclick but currently I get all values checked and you can't uncheck them

> NB: Also tried using defaultCheck instead of checked which after onClick would produce the map is undefined error

Comment: try `onChange={this.handleChange}` instead of onClick

Comment: @PrabhatMishra I tried `OnChange={this.handleChange}` still the same outcome. Doesn't it somehow require the payload to be changed to `flavour: {Spicy : false, Hot: false}` as currently its just `flavour: {Spicy, Hot}`. This is where I think the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox values don't need a true or false, it either checked or nothing. So all I had to do was remove `checked={item}` that was what was keeping the checkboxes ticked whether I changed the state or not.

Answer (score 1):

In `getAllFlavours` ,I don't know whether you should received checked/Unchecked values from api but while setting state in `getAllFlavours` you can set it something like this then:

```
let flavourLists = { [name] : { isChecked : false } };
```

and overwrite the checked value in `handleCheckboxChange` like this then:

`this.setState({ flavours: { ...this.state.flavours ,[name] : { isChecked : true } }  })`

access the state values accordingly in render now.

Comment: Thank you lend me in the right direction. My issue was actually `checked={item}` after removing that it worked fine.